# XSLT: find first element above selected element

Tags: xslt, xpath, docx

I want to get the first heading (h1) before a table in a docx.

I can get all headings with:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='berschrift1']]">
    <p>
        <context>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </context>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

and I can also get all tables

```
<xsl:template match="w:tbl">
    <p>
    <table>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </table>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

But unfortunetly the processor does not accept

```
<xsl:template match="w:tbl/preceding-sibling::w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='berschrift1']]">
    <p>
    <table>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </table>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a reduced XML file extracted from a docx: http://pastebin.com/KbUyzRVv
I want something like that as a result:

```
<context>Let’s get it on</context> <- my heading
<table>data</table>

<context>Let’s get it on</context> <- my heading
<table>data</table>

<context>We’re in the middle of something</context> <- my heading
<table>data</table>
```

Thanks to Daniel Haley I was able to find a solution for that problem. I'll post it here, so it is independend of the pastebin I postet below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl w v">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="w:tbl">
            <context>
                <xsl:value-of select="(preceding-sibling::w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val = 'berschrift1']])[last()]"/>
            </context>
            <table>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Always specify whether you can take advantage of XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first approach to do something with XSLT. It is also a prototype, so I think as long as there are non commercial processor the version does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but try this:

```
<xsl:template match="w:tbl">
  <p>
    <table>
      <xsl:value-of select="(preceding::w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='berschrift1']])[last()]"/>
    </table>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think it is close to a solution. Your statement finds the same heading, but not the first above the table. I added a pastebin with my test-xml in it. The current xsl is here: http://pastebin.com/M3kDmf1V

Comment: @froehli - The XSLT in your pastebin is missing the most important piece; you need to wrap everything in the `select` in `()[1]` (full select: `select="(preceding::w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='berschrift1']])[1]"`).

Comment: The array here contains two elements for every table. With [1] the first one is chosen all the time. But the heading need to change. So neither with [1] nor without I get the right heading.
I tried something that seems to work here: http://pastebin.com/ZnXy11NP

Comment: I would use `preceding::X[filter][1]` in preference to `(preceding::X[filter])[last()]`. They are equivalent, but the former is likely to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use XSLT 2.0 (and most people can, nowadays), I find a useful technique here is to have a global variable that selects all the relevant nodes:

```
<xsl:variable name="special" 
  select="//w:tbl/preceding-sibling::w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='berschrift1']][1]"/>
```

and then use this variable in a template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[. intersect $special]"/>
```

In XSLT 3.0 you can reduce this to

```
<xsl:template match="$special"/>
```